# Accessing Specific Element from List of Pairs in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue, dijkstra

I want to skip large weights in case of multiple edges. I think the code can be optimized if I can access the weight directly between the edges u and v. The code is from Dijkstra Algorithm by using priority queue. I can iterate and check but I think it's not efficient. How can I optimize the code?

```
void Graph::addEdge(long long int u, long long int v, long long int weight){

    list<pair<long long int,long long int> >::iterator i;

    int flag = 0;
    for(i = adj[u].begin(); i!= adj[u].end(); ++i){
        if((*i).first == v && weight>(*i).second){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        return;
    }

    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, weight));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, weight));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest some optimizations to this code:

1. Use std::vector or std::array instead of std::list. list is implemented as linked list and traversal is *slow*. vector and array are cache-friendlier as well since data is stored sequentially and thus, more than one elements will be loaded at once in the cache.
2. Using an array/vector of an unordered_map instead of every pairs such that `adj[u]` will correspond to a hash map with node `v` as key and min weight as the value. To improve the performance of this hash map further, you can provide a custom hash function and a custom collision resolution method as well after going through the default behavior and if it suits your case. Otherwise std::unordered_map is quite efficient as it is.
   **Do note that using unordered_map is only more beneficial in case of insertion/queries** For traversal, it's sad.